# Definite integral of Airy function

Tags: complex-analysis, matlab

I am trying to understand how $\int_{constant}^\infty Ai(x')dx'$ behaves when the inferior limit is properly a constant "1, 3, 8, etc" all the way to $\infty$

I am using the following in matlab

```
eta01=-1.1379 - 0.6569i;
airy_INT1=integral(@(n) airy(n),eta01,1000000);
```

Obtaining zero while, if instead of 1000000 I use 100, I get a non-zero value.
I used to think that when eta>around 10, the function is effectively almost zero, but it turns out that the integral is quite sensible, isn't it? Is it that I am not understanding something or an issue with the MATLAB integral function?

Comment: I cannot help with MATLAB, but may be you can use the closed form from 
http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.10.E1
$$\int_{z}^{\infty}\mathrm{Ai}\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t=\pi\left(\mathrm{Ai}
\left(z\right)\mathrm{Gi}'\left(z\right)-\mathrm{Ai}'\left(z\right)\mathrm{Gi}\left(z\right)\right)$$
or the asymptotic expansion for $x \rightarrow \infty$ from
http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.10.E4
$$\int_{x}^{\infty}\mathrm{Ai}\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t\sim\tfrac{1}{2}\pi^{-1/2 }x^{-3/4}\exp\left({-}\tfrac{2}{3}x^{3/2}\right)$$

Comment: The Scorer's function actually includes the integral, so it doesn't solve my question :(

Comment: Is there a reason `eta01` is complex in your example even though you mention real-valued lower limits in the text just above? If the lower limit is complex, you should be able to use `Inf` as your upper limit for `integral`.